# Flexbox - aligning the third item in relation to second

Tags: css, flexbox

I have three flex items all with different height and different widths.

I want the second and third items to be in relation to the first.

My first item is a image, second a text, third another text

I want my second item to be at the center of the flex box and the third to be at the start of second item. I also want the second item to grow and cover the rem area.

[How I want my alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjpIr.png)

This is what I am doing

```
.box {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;

}

.flex-second-item {
align-self: center;
flex-grow: 1
}
```

Comment: _"This is what I am doing"_ - doing to what? Present a _proper_ [mre] please, when asking this type of question.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to achieve what you want regarding _"the third to be at the start of second"_ with flexbox, other than to wrap 2 & 3 into an additional container element.

Comment: Have you investigated CSS grid? And could you describe how the second box's vertical position is decided?

Comment: you have to make your question clear, I think this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use different flexboxes for them

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.right-side {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.two {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: red;
 }
 
 .three {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Hope it helps.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap second and third item in a div, and you display flex them with align-items=flex-start.

So you may try :

```
.first-box-and-div-which-contains-second-and-third-boxes {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.second-and-third-boxes {
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
}
```